# ActionController::UnknownFormat when uploading image with Dropzone

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a new error regarding my Dropzone JS snippet. I use dropzone to upload images from an #Edit view.

One the images are created by another controller create action, I redirect to that very edit action.

This is where I get this new error :

```
Completed 406 Not Acceptable in 14ms (ActiveRecord: 1.1ms)



ActionController::UnknownFormat (PhotographesController#edit is missing a template for this request format and variant.

request.formats: ["application/json"]
request.variant: []):

actionpack (5.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:42:in `default_render'
actionpack (5.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/basic_implicit_render.rb:6:in `block in send_action'
actionpack (5.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/basic_implicit_render.rb:6:in `tap'
actionpack (5.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/basic_implicit_render.rb:6:in `send_action'
actionpack (5.2.0) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:194:in `process_action'
.....
```

It used to work perfectly in the past. But since I have set this snippet in place I have done quite a few things: installing `gem "serviceworker-rails"` and deferring the javascript..

I have undeferred the Javascript but the error is still here. Is it related to the serviceworker gem ?

EDIT

Dropzone snippet inside Photographes#edit view (inline)

```
<script>

  // Dropzone = dynamic



  var AUTH_TOKEN=$('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content');
    Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
    var myDropzone = new Dropzone("div#mydropzone",{
        url: "<%= photographe_photographephotos_path(@photographe.hashed_id) %>",
        autoProcessQueue: false,
        autoDiscover: false,
        uploadMultiple: true,
        addRemoveLinks: true,
        // clickable: false,
        parallelUploads: 12,
        maxFilesize: 5,
        maxFiles: 12,
        acceptedFiles: 'image/jpg, image/jpeg, image/png',
        params:{
            'authenticity_token':  AUTH_TOKEN
        },
        successmultiple: function(data,response){
            $('#msgBoard').append(response.message).addClass("alert alert-success");
            $('#msgBoard').delay(2000).fadeOut();
            $('#fileslist').val(response.filesList);
            $('#photographedit').off('submit').submit();
        }
    });
    $('#photographedit').submit(function(e){
        if(myDropzone.getQueuedFiles().length > 0){
            e.preventDefault();
            myDropzone.processQueue();
        }
    });

</script>
```

Then Photographephotos#create

```
def create
    @photographe = Photographe.find_by(hashed_id: params[:photographe_hashed_id])

    if params[:file].present?
      uploaded_pics = params[:file]
      maximum_images=12
      available_images = maximum_images - @photographe.photographephotos.count

      n_keys = uploaded_pics.keys.first(available_images)
      filtered_pics = uploaded_pics.slice(*n_keys)

      filtered_pics.each do |index,pic|
         @image = @photographe.photographephotos.new
         @image.image = pic
         @image.image_file_name = "Copyright" + @photographe.professionnel.first_name.to_s  + @photographe.professionnel.last_name.to_s + ".JPG"
         @image.save
      end
    end
    redirect_to edit_photographe_path(@photographe.hashed_id)
  end
```

The redirect at the end returns (should return) to the Photographes#edit view. What is funny if it used to work properly ...

I see that people used to have same problem with `Jbuilder` as per github. I have updated `Jbuilder` gem with no success.

Also the pictures are properly updated by `paperclip`. I get this error from logs when the redirection fails at the end of the images creation.

Comment: Show your controller, it's trying to render a json view but you are not responding to that or you are missing a template for that format.

Comment: Ok it seems I have a really poor way of handling Dropzone (not async above). It should indeed return json. I will rewrite my Dropzone code..

Answer (score 1):

It seems like the controller is trying to render a template in a format that doesn't exist, maybe you can try specifying the format explicitly like this:

```
redirect_to edit_photographe_path(@photographe.hashed_id), :format => :html
```

This may happen if you received a request in a specific format and want to render a template in a different one.

I'm not sure if, in your case, the :format option should go inside the _path() or the redirect_to() method. If the  above doesn't work try this:

```
redirect_to edit_photographe_path(@photographe.hashed_id, :format => :html)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Gus. What I didn't understand is that this problem happened only recently. I am using Dropzone as a pretty input file tag. All files were sent as a whole when submit button pressed... I have fixed by just using Dropbox as intended: Ajax post of files one by one. This now work without error and is more efficient.

Comment: Beats me.. I guess by adding Dropzone something in the upload request header changed ? You could inspect that using Postman.

Comment: I am not very familiar with Ajax, my Rails app is really only a website at the moment. I have very limited knowledge of APIs, JS, Ajax .. So when something is a bit hybrid .. I am ... quite lost. Actually I am learning JS at the moment so I guess I will be more familiar with this in the future ..